# Javax.validation throwing 500 error instead of 400

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-validator

I have simple javax.validation. Bean validation works fine  but  when validation fails instead of throwing 400 it is throwing 500 Error.

[Click here to check  API response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXk70.png)

Comment: You should handle the exception using Exception Handler.

Comment: I think it's normal to have a 500 error. Because you're not yet able to send the value to the backend to validate. If you're sending a null value to the backend from the controller, you should indicate it as required false using @RequestParam(required = false) or sth. similar. Please share your controller methods to make it more clear

Comment: @Eklavya fixed with Exception Handler. Thank you